# when I request the data in gastby to the api of gastby, there 405 error

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

this is the front-end code:

```
const result = await fetch(`/api/sendMail`, {
        method: `POST`,
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      });
      if (!result.ok) {
        toast.error('send email error');
      } else {
        toast.success('send email success, please check');
      }
```

and then I create `api` directory, and create `sendMail.js` file, the code is:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === `POST`) {
    const { toEmail, subject, content } = req.body;
    try {
      await fetch('https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          personalizations: [
            {
              to: [
                {
                  email: toEmail,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
          from: {
            email: process.env.FROM_EMAIL,
          },
          subject,
          content: [
            {
              type: 'text/plain',
              value: `please click ${content}`,
            },
          ],
        }),
      });
      res.status(200).json({});
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'method is wrong' });
  }
}
```

when run the code in the local environment, it is ok. But when I deploy to the production environment, it has the 405 error code.